# How to make request through VPN using RestAssured and proxy

Tags: vpn, apache-httpclient-4.x, rest-assured

- I try to make requests to the host, using VPN.
- I get the IP with which I can open VPN connection via proxy options
- I can get to the needed host using chrome-driver

But I just need to send GET request via my VPN IP - this will be enough.
How can implement it using RestAssured or Apache http-client?

Comment: Have you tried get into IP to make a VPN connection, and from this IP make a request to host? What do you really want? a simple rest-assured code?

Comment: @lucasnguyen17 The server registers an activity via VPN. I create proxy-options for WebDriver, which gives the possibility to use a certain website through certain IP(s). But it takes a lot of time (I need to create 1000 requests from different IPs) - so I decided to create GET request through other IP (VPN), using proxy.

Comment: I think this one will help you. https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#proxy-configuration